# SIdeloading uwp app to mobile device

Tags: mobile, uwp, windows-10-universal, sideloading

I am following this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/install-universal-windows-apps-with-the-winappdeploycmd-tool to sideload an app on a phone.

I am having trouble understanding what is meant by .appx file.

> WinAppDeployCmd install -file "Downloads\MyApp.appx" -ip 192.168.0.1 -pin A1B2C3

I creqate dhte app package but searching the app folder for .appx files does not  yield "myapp".appx.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .appx file is associated with AppX application distribution file format introduced in Microsoft Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 operating systems. It's now used for Windows Ten systems. Similar to a .xap file. To find the .appx file in your Visual Studio Project, go to Documents/Visual Studio/Projects. Open your project folder, then you can find your .appx file.

For Windows 8.1 Store Apps, see [Windows 8.1 Store apps: Install and test an app on other devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY6az.jpg). For Windows 10 Store Apps, see [Windows 10 Application Deployment Tool](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/09/just-released-windows-10-application-deployment-tool/).

Comment: The only file close in the project folder is Package.appxmanifest. Then  - WinAppDeployCmd install -file "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PhoneApp\PhoneApp\Package.appxmanifest" -ip 111.0.0.1- does not work, neither does Package.appxmanifest.

Comment: The highlighted files are the .appx files of an app in the following image. http://imgur.com/kLXdCNU

Comment: This link shows the project file contents: http://imgur.com/a/IlkpZ . There are no .appx files.

Comment: In the AppPackages folder, go into the Test folder, and the .appxbundle or .appx file should do. The Test folder is highlighted in the shown image. http://imgur.com/oH0geuZ

Comment: Glad to know it helped.